# Web API cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix

Tags: r, api

I am creating an API in R with Plumber which takes in typed coordinates, then using the function below to converts the coordinates to a spatial point for use in the API

```
def_coord <- function(x, y){
  xy <- data.frame(x, y)
  ll_prj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" # set projection
  SpatialPoints(xy, proj4string=CRS(ll_prj))
  return(xy)
}
```

Here is the parameter argument in the api

```
#* @param y Latitude in decimal degrees.
#* @param x Longitude in decimal degrees.
```

On execution, the API returns the error below:

```
 <simpleError in .local(obj, ...): cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you give a complete minimal example of all the code you have and how you are running the API service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert x and y from characters to numeric:

```
#* @param y Latitude in decimal degrees.
#* @param x Longitude in decimal degrees.
#* @get /coord
def_coord <- function(x, y){
    library(sp)
    x = as.numeric(x)  # this
    y = as.numeric(y)  # and this
    xy <- data.frame(x, y)
    ll_prj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" # set projection
    SpatialPoints(xy, proj4string=CRS(ll_prj))
    return(xy)
}
```

with that in `ll.R`, the following works:

```
> r = plumb("./ll.R")
> r$run()
Starting server to listen on port 3317
Running the swagger UI at http://127.0.0.1:3317/__swagger__/
```

and accessing the server that URL lets me explore the UI and run an example which returns a JSON version of the data frame.